# Protractor testing a specific cell in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e, end-to-end

I need to locate and test a specific cell in an ng-grid table to ensure it's not showing 'NaN'. I have been able to locate cells in columns 1-7, but this cell is in column 14, which a user needs to scroll horizontally to see. When trying to locate cells 8-14, protractor just returns undefined. I've tried resizing the window before the test, to no avail.

Code:

```
it('should have values in the adverse events tab for the Fosamax column when viewing Postmenopausal Osteoporosis report', function () {

    browser.get('/#/druggroup/indication/N0000003303/adverseevents/IR');

    var fosamaxCell = element.all(by.repeater('row in renderedRows')).then(function(rows) {
        cell = rows[6].element(by.className('colt14')).getText()
            .then(function (data) {
            return data.replace(/ /g,'');
        });
        return cell;
    });

    expect(fosamaxCell).toEqual('NaN');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Scrolling into view*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView) should help here:

```
var elm = rows[6].element(by.className('colt14'));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elm.getWebElement());
cell = elm.getText().then(function (data) {
    return data.replace(/ /g,'');
});
```